How to specify path to source_directory in ScriptRunConfig in Azureml
I am trying to execute a training script in Azure. I configured the ScriptRunConfig using:
script_config = ScriptRunConfig(
    source_directory='flightdelayMLfolder',
    script='training_script.py',
    environment=env
)

When I try to run the experiment using:
experiment = Experiment(ws, name='flightdelayMLscript')
run = experiment.submit(config=script_config)
RunDetails(run).show()
run.wait_for_completion()

 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/,,,,/code/Users/,,,/outputs/MLfolder'

The folders outputs and flightdelayMLfolder are two folders inside my account folder in Azure. i.e:
/Users/myaccount/outputs
/Users/myaccount/flightdelayMLfolder

When I try to give the full path to flightdelayMLfolder : /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters..... I get script path doesn't exist. The script should be inside the project folder" error
Could anyone please let me know how to make sure the path to the source_directly be accurately mentioned in the ScriptRunConfig
Adding folder structure:


To ensure the path to the source_directory in ScriptRunConfig is correctly specified and recognized by Azure ML, ensure that the paths are correctly relative to your working directory when you submit the script.

or from notebook

Here I have created an environment.yml file and training_script.py in MLfolder and kept the config.json under Python Codes (outside MLfolder)
# MLfolder/environment.yml

name: my-environment

dependencies:

- python=3.8

- numpy

- pip:

- azureml-defaults

MLfolder/training_script.py
# main.py

from  azureml.core  import  Workspace, Experiment, ScriptRunConfig, Environment

import  logging

  

# Load the workspace from the config file

ws = Workspace.from_config()

  

# Create an environment (you can also use an existing one)

env = Environment.from_conda_specification(

name='my-environment',

file_path='Python Codes/MLfolder/environment.yml'

)

# Define the ScriptRunConfig

script_config = ScriptRunConfig(

source_directory='Python Codes', # This should be the relative path to your source directory

script='MLfolder/training_script.py', # This should be the script name inside the source directory

arguments=['--data-path', 'MLfolder/data/train-data.csv'], # Specify any arguments your script needs

environment=env

)

  

# Create and submit the experiment

experiment = Experiment(workspace=ws, name='MLscript')

run = experiment.submit(config=script_config)

  

# Monitor the run

logging.info("Run ID: {}".format(run.id))

logging.info("Experiment Name: {}".format(run.experiment.name))

  

run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)



Ensure the source_directory in ScriptRunConfig is specified as a relative path from where you run the main.py script. In my case, source_directory='MLfolder' means it is relative to C:\Users\arko\Codes\Arko-Codes\Arko-Codes\Python Codes.

Could you please let me know how to set relative path? I am struggling with that. And my MLfolder folder has only the training_script.py file. My yml and executor.ipynb files are in outputs folder

I tried ../MLfolder and also copying path to folder and pasting it in the ScriptRunConfig, still it's not working

I moved the training_script.py to outputs folder. i.e. all my files are in outputs folder, still getting this error : /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/xxx/code/Users/xxx/outputs/training_script.py script path doesn't exist. The script should be inside the project folder

@KarthikS Please add the screenshot of the folder structure like how it is added in the solution.

@JayashankarGS, have added now

Can you debug training script. The error may be from training script.

Can you try it fresh? Clean slate. Create a folder named Karthik and inside that create MLfolder, inside MLfolder put your training and environment file. Come outside MLfolder and inside the main folder i.e. Karthik, place your config and main.py , now just to validate your path just do a mkdir -p MLfolder/data
echo "1,2,3" > MLfolder/data/train-data.csv and do a pwd followed by ls or dir to confirm the same. Cross check your source path inside main.py. update the source_directory='karthik' and script='MLfolder/training_script.py' and run the code under Notebook.
